# Singleton.Instance = Lazy.Value?

Tags: c#, singleton, lazy-evaluation

Can we say making a class `Lazy` is like making it `Singleton` ?

In both case we create the instance via a property and access to the same instance (if it's created) in further usages.

Comment: I'm not sure if I missed something about them or not. For example if they are the same why we bother implementing `Singleton` pattern, we can just make it `Lazy`. I what to know if there are differences I ignored.

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @Slaks: very useful link. Specially #4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

Lazy initialisation of a variable only affects that variable, it doesn't make the class a singleton, or even reuse instances between variables. If you for example have two variables of the type `Lazy<MyClass>`, they would still create separate instances of the class.

A singleton usually uses lazy intialisation internally, but it doesn't have to. It could also be implemented using early initalisation, and just return the already created instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, do you want a class in the singleton pattern with lazy initialization?

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private Singleton() { }
   static Lazy<Singleton> instance = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

   public static Singleton Instance
      {
          get
          {
              return instance.Value;
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Common `Singleton` pattern use `Lazy` instantiating by default. Using `MEF` the `container` hold reference to `imports` and doesn't create new instances. Since I was imported my parts lazily, I forget this is the `MEF` behavior not `Lazy` itself. Thanks for sample code.

Comment: @SLaks: Em..I didn't use a nested class, but I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: You don't need a `Lazy<T>` at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can have an object that is lazy but there can be multiple instances of the same object. Singleton would exist once and only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is a lazy class - but you can have more than one
class Lazy
{
    private int? _value;
    public int Value {
        get
        {
           return _value ?? (_value = new Random().Next()).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

you can of course make `Value` static so that all `Lazy`s have the same Value

Comment: `make a class Lazy` != `make a class named Lazy`, even if I don't know what's the meaning of `make a class lazy`.

Comment: class `Lazy` has property called `Value`, which is Lazy. If I were to `make a class lazy` I would do that for all properties.